# Exception in native call from JS error when triggering Audio Recording function using react-native-audio-recorder-player

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to implement a recording function using react-native-audio-recorder-player, but whenever I try to trigger the onStartRecord() function I receive the following error :

[image]

My code for the onStartRecord() being:

```
const onStartRecord = async () => {
    let iswritestoragegranted = await writetoexternalstorage();
    let isrecordgranted = await recordaudiopermission();
    if (iswritestoragegranted && isrecordgranted) {
      const path = "sdcard/hello.m4a";
      const audioSet = {
        AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
        AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
        AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
      };
      console.log("audioSet", audioSet);
      const uri = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet);
      audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
        setRecordSecs(e.current_position);
        setRecordTime(
          audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.current_position))
        );
      });
      console.log(`uri: ${uri}`);
    }
  };
```

my console shows the following :

[image]

after this it crashes and shows the above error.

Have been trying to implement since a week now, and have not no clue why this keeps crashing, kindly let me know where have I gone wrong here and how could I resolve this. it would be a great help.
Thanking you in advance.
Let me know, if anything else is required for better understanding.

Thanks you

Comment: This is the Native Android Code exception that occurred in setAudioSource method of  RNAudioRecorderModule.java that caused due to the call of startRecoring from javascript.

Comment: how do I resolve that?

Comment: This is the library issue or the issue in the usage of the library that maybe not according to the library documentation. Be sure that you have performed all the steps and taken user permission according to the package documentation.

Comment: Try adding 
`{ ext { androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"   androidXBrowser = "1.0.0" } }` 
in app/build.gradle in `buildscript` block.

Also, check if you've added 
`PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
in the manifest file, too.

Comment: ^ make that `android/build.gradle`